# What would need to be changed to create a new standard stream?

Tags: devices, streams

Hopefully this question isn't too abstract, it touches on a bunch of software throughout the stack.

We all know about /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout, and /dev/stderr. What if I wanted to create a new standard stream, /dev/stdjson? What software would need to support that? I'm assuming that I don't *need* to pass a file descriptor to /dev/stdjson to every program, that they can open that stream on an as-needed basis. So where could you add a new standard stream? Would it need to be a kernal module, a part of the shell?

Comment: Could you possibly give some background to your question, a reason for needing a new _standard_ stream? Also, what would be communicated on this stream that could not be communicated on the standard input, standard output, or the standard error stream?

Comment: I'm not expecting to actually *do* this, to be clear. There are a lot of suggestions on how to pipe structured data between programs. There are tools like the relatively new "jc" which provide generic parsers for textual output of a bunch of programs. There's whatever power-shell is doing...

A new stream is another way to handle it, and I'd love to talk about the advantages and disadvantages of that approach, but I don't think stack exchange will let me as it's too broad of a topic.

Comment: The thing about the standard streams is that there is _nothing_ saying anything about what _format_ the data should have on these streams.  In fact, data may be JSON, GZip compressed binary, line-based text records, CSV, or whatever else.  It sounds as if you're talking about a stream that enforces something like a standard format.  Is that correct?

Comment: I think there's a big difference between machine-optimized and person-optimized formats. Json is an obvious option for a machine-optimized format, but I wouldn't want LS to output json by default. A /dev/stddata node could make sense as well, which could support multiple machine-readable data formats. I think the important thing is to have a separate stream for machine-readable data. Alternatively a way to tell if the command ahead in the pipeline wants machine-readable data could be nice. The same way color gets "magically" stripped if you're piping to not a tty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about the standard streams is that they're assumed to be available when a process starts, which means that file descriptors to them *are* passed to every program. ([It's even allowed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/execve.html) for the system to open some unspecified file on those file descriptors if they otherwise would remain closed after `execve()`.) The other thing that makes those streams standard, is that the C runtime library creates the `FILE` objects corresponding to standard input, output and error so the user program can use e.g. `fprintf()` and other `stdio.h` functions on them immediately.

The "devices" `/dev/stdin` etc. are unrelated to that, but are system-specific ways of accessing those file descriptors (or the underlying files) via *names*. If you look at e.g. `/dev/stdin` on Linux, it's a symlink that points to `/proc/self/fd/0`, which itself is a magic kernel interface to file descriptor 0 of the current process. Without that fd open `/dev/stdin` itself doesn't do anything.

So, to add a new "standard stream", you'd need to change the C library, and possibly a number of programs that treat fds 0, 1 and 2 specially when starting programs.

---

But if you're talking about processes opening the file as needed, it sounds a bit different than what the standard streams are. Of course, you can create a named file somewhere that your programs are allowed to assume is present. But what that file would do, and if it would be a regular file, a pipe or a socket, depends on what you're actually trying to do. Also, if it's specific to some program or set of programs, it might be better placed in something like `/var/lib/mytool`, than in `/dev/`.